# Xplot for jupyter: "no template named decay_t in namespace std"

Tags: c++, jupyter, jupyter-lab, xeus-cling

I am trying to include a couple xplot files, but I get this very cryptic error message: [image] 
Does anyone know why? I have already installed xplot and xeus-cling via conda.

Comment: Please post all code and errors as text.  `std::decay_t` requires C++14 see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay

Comment: The file your error mentions also contains the definition of `std::decay_t`, but it is hidden by an `#if __cplusplus >= 201402L`. According to the GCC documentation, C++14 should be the default since 6.1. Can you show how xplot invokes gcc or add the `-std=c++14` flag to make c++14 explicit?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the info. I have just switched my kernel to c++14, and it works now! I didn't realize std::decay_t was only c++14 and above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just solved this problem: it turns out std::decay_t is only supported in c++14 and later, so I switched my kernel to c++14 and now it works properly.